# Can I infer types based on other properties in an object?

Tags: typescript

I've noticed a pattern in my code and I feel like there's a better solution for this.

Let's say I have these basic entities

```
type User = {
  id: string,
}

type Company = {
  id: number,
}

enum Member {
 Company = "Company",
 Member = "Member",
}
```

Now oftentimes I'm passing around payloads like this

```
type Payload = {
  type: Member,
  payload: Company["id"][] | User["id"][] // string[] | number[]
}
```

Now the question is, can I infer the type of the payload if I have checked the type? Right now I have to declare the type.

```
if (payload.type === Member.Company)
   result = (payload.payload as number[]).map(etc) // have to declare type of array, how to infer?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for that to work, you want your `Payload` type to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions).  Right now, your `Payload` is a non-union type, each of whose properties is a union; as such, it can accept values you don't want, such as where the `type` is `Company` but the `payload` has an `id` from `User`.  The union should be pushed up to the top level, where you spell out the relationship involved:

```
type Payload =
  { type: Member.Company, payload: Company["id"][] } |
  { type: Member.Member, payload: User["id"][] };
```

Now that we have a top-level union, and since each member's `type` property is a unit type (only has a single possible value), the compiler will understand checking `type` to discriminate the union:

```
  if (payload.type === Member.Company) {
    payload.payload.map(x => x + 1); // okay
  } else {
    payload.payload.map(x => x.toUpperCase()); // okay
  }
```

---

If you have lots of enum members you might consider making a mapping interface representing the relationship between each enum member and the object it points to, and using it to calculate `Payload` so that you don't have to write out a big union with nearly identical `{type: Member.XXX, payload: YYY["id"][]}` members:

```
interface MemberMapping {
  [Member.Company]: Company;
  [Member.Member]: User;
}

type Payload = {
  [K in Member]: { type: K, payload: MemberMapping[K]["id"][] }
}[Member];
/* type Payload = {
    type: Member.Company;
    payload: number[];
} | {
    type: Member.Member;
    payload: string[];
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBSgSwBMAuKOYRfAOwHMAaHAXxx1EigGEB7AWzAEMqIVBhx4ipKgFceAIyQNszbDgjSeUALIQ5SUbk68BQkQCJufQSFOK823cjSn78xDaYtsAegBUbaAAK-CAANlz8hCJYBv6kLgpiUAKh4SSGlkIA2qZEpgC6mXlQAD6wCIjZuQVFXl5kFNQ0hSVQ6q6FTD5enr5Q-lBBKRGoieh94BBxOq4AdBbGIHRJwWERpPNWlYT5zYwlo+OQUw4z8YhLyatp8EhbO0WMANw4XZ7UwEgAZvwAxtBnmn4YDAjX0eEyZzmRiseXW0KEzwMEOmSFOKMQsLKSERylYEwGK1SUUSmQA0gQqFp0ZixrEoKSLoS1lSHIDgY0yQUcttqlBlIxkQ48ojev1BldiQY8HTIRsEYk8JdUpIZO1hUwWtE8NKJsdZmdEdrlkM0uRKLRCjioK8VNhPlIqD9gPguJTPlwuAAKJXM8WpACU+kS+E+UG9TMIM36KBjLNmcpAga12p9kdTMx4QM9AA9UAA+KC5gDUUAAjP7EnsICEEGCUxGZunM2Ac-nC1GuDBgUgOPwEJ7-f7DXymEA)

Comment: The second implementation is what i was looking for! Actually I almost had it like this. Could it be that interfaces don't allow declarations like `[K in Member]` ? I remember trying something along those lines with an interface.

Comment: yes, `{[K in Member]: ...}` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), and interfaces are not mapped types.